# Does Mono have a hot swapping feature?

Tags: mono

When I code in Java, I can use tools like JRebel to allow me to see changes immediately without restarting the server. (I'm embedding the JVM into a c application, so I don't want to constantly restart the c application for every Java source code change)
Does Mono have something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar by using application domains (load the new code in a new appdomain, unload the old one etc).